Tengo problemas con hacer un proyecto maven
me surgio un problema con la creacion de un proyecto maven, cree un proyecto con archetype.quizstar de apache maven, pero cuando compilo el proyecto que se genero me sale un error y todavia no empece aun el programa que quiero hacer, queria compilar el Hello word del main.Este es el error que sale.
´´´
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.208 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-10-23T01:54:25-03:00
[INFO]------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: pre-clean, clean, post-clean, validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException

´´´
y como especifico el goal y que me comviene poner en el goal para un proyecto simple que consulta a una en una base de datos mysql

Buenas, dejaré este comentario para aquellos que han dado -1, sin dar contexto de nada, o que está mal en la publicación. El error es suficientemente descriptivo, para entregar una respuesta completa sobre maven. Como mencioné en mi respuesta, el mismo error describe soluciones, pero está en inglés, asi que las traducciones igual son respuesta.

Tal y como has mencionado, no has específicado el goal.
El mismo error al final, te entrega una guía para que compruebes activar el goal.
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoGoalSpecifiedException
Un goal en Maven es una tarea específica que Maven ejecuta durante el ciclo de vida de construcción del proyecto. Cada goal representa una acción, como compilar el código, empaquetar los archivos en un JAR/WAR, ejecutar pruebas, limpiar el proyecto, entre otras.
Lo más simple, para no estar usando comandos como los de la explicación, es ir directamente al POM y ponerlo ahi.
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
    ...
  </build>
  ...
</project>

De todos modos, no siempre necesitas especificar un goal porque Maven ejecuta automáticamente los goals relacionados con cada fase del ciclo de vida.
Solo es necesario especificar un goal explícitamente si deseas realizar una tarea específica o utilizar un plugin sin pasar por todas las fases del ciclo de vida.
Además, te dejo la guía de  introducción a los ciclos de vida de maven.
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html
Y otra de explicación de que es el goal como tal en español.
https://www.arquitecturajava.com/que-es-un-maven-goal/

Muchas gracias me lo resolviste. Y gracias por la info

Por favor, dame +1 y marca la respuesta como correcta. Ayuda mucho, no solo a mi, sino a el problema y su solución.

Ya te puntue, con +1 crack

Solo para confirmar, el +1 diría +1 en la publicación, dice 0, y a parte, la respuesta correcta. Y gracias por marcarla correcta

cuando pongo el +1 vuelve a 0 pero la marque como correcta

A entonces se demorará en aplicar el +1, dejalo puesto y gracias :D

dale. gracias por tu ayuda.
